# Condições em Query SQL

Tags: mysql

Olá, precisaria de uma ajuda, gostaria de trazer somente o funcionário que não tem a palavra NR-35 na tabela/coluna funcionarioscursospd/pdf, meu problema é que eu tenho mais de um curso vinculado ao mesmo usuário.

```
SELECT fd.id,
       fd.nome,
       fd.cpf,
       fd.cursos
FROM   funcionariosdoc AS fd
INNER  JOIN funcionarioscursospdf AS fc
ON     fd.id = fc.id_func
WHERE  fd.cursos LIKE '%NR-35%'
AND    fc.pdf NOT LIKE '%NR-35%'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá, esta consulta resolve o seu problema:

```
SELECT fd.id,
       fd.nome,
       fd.cpf,
       fd.cursos
FROM   funcionariosdoc AS fd
WHERE  fd.cursos LIKE '%NR-35%'
AND    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
        FROM   funcionarioscursospdf AS fc
        WHERE  fd.id = fc.id_func
        AND    fc.pdf LIKE '%NR-35%')
```

## Explicando:

alterei a sua condição `fc.pdf NOT LIKE '%NR-35%'` para uma consulta que procura na tabela funcionarioscursospdf um funcionario que atenda a condição `LIKE '%NR-35%'` e retorne falso caso exista

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou!